# Aurelia component's canDeactivate method called erroneously on redirects

Tags: aurelia

There is a [bug in Aurelia](https://github.com/aurelia/router/issues/45) where a component's canDeactivate method is called multiple times per router activation cycle if there are one or more redirects when navigating to another route. Upon navigating away from the current route, canDeactivate is called like normal, and then it is called again for each redirect.

Has anyone come up with a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

The best I could come up with was to throttle canDeactivate at 2 seconds.